# React Native Rename app with special characters

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to rename the react native app (Folder and package names not the app name) with special characters but its not allowing to rename, but I can create the app with special characters. is there any way to rename the app with special characters?

npx react-native-rename My_App
"My_App" is not a valid name for a project. Please use a valid identifier name (alphanumeric and space).

Comment: do you want to change the app name or project name?

Comment: @codehesh Project name, folders and package names